# Python tkinter save new results in text file

Tags: python, tkinter, load, overwrite

I would like to ask a question about loading a certain txt file in python with `tkinter`, or any other method that I could use. Here is the "test" program that I made.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40k2K.png)

Every button calculates a certain percentage of the entered number.
After I enter a number and calculate the percentage of that number, say I enter 100 and 80% of that is 80. The result is displayed, and after that I would like to save that result in a text file, using `"Add new max"` button.
After the result is saved when I open the program it should display `"Current max: 80"`. So basically save the calculated result and display it every time I open the program.

Say that the `"current saved result"` is `80` and I calculate a new one which is greater than `current result(80)` and it is thus replaced.

In the image that I attached:

```
      test1 = x
```

and if the new value that I enter is greater than x, that x should be replaced by new value. (ignore test2, test3)

What should I use in order to do that?

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Which part are you unsure how to do? Writing a file? Reading it? Triggering the save event when a button is pressed?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what **specifically** do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too difficult.

To write a file:

```
f = open( 'name_of_a_file', 'w' ) #(w = write)
f.write(some_data_or_something)
f.close()
```

To read a file:

```
try:
    fh = open('name_of_a_file', "r")
    some_data = fh.read()
    fh.close()

except IOError:
    print("could not load the file.")
```

**Complete code - saves a file, then pulls it back in and prints it:

```
some_data_or_something = 'hello'
f = open( 'name_of_a_file', 'w' ) #(w = write)
f.write(some_data_or_something)
f.close()

try:
    fh = open('name_of_a_file', "r") #(r = read)
    some_data = fh.read()
    fh.close()
    print(some_data)

except IOError:
    print("could not load the file.")
```